# How detect correct date format in R by number?

Tags: r, date, format

I have a dataset where the "Date" feature has numbers from 41870 to 43511.
Conversion to "Date" format gives the following results:

```
as.Date(41870) => "2084-08-20"
as.Date(43511) => "2089-02-16"
```

I think it can be related to the "format" option. But how detect the correct format for "date" automatic or by hand?

Comment: What is your expected result? i.e., what is the correct format? R doesn't know, I don't know, do you know?

Comment: Did this come from Excel? Googling "excel date origin" says that Excel uses `1899-12-30` as the origin on Windows, and `1904-01-01` as the origin on Mac, so depending on the Excel user's OS, the correct answer *might* be `as.Date(41870, origin = "1899-12-30")` or `as.Date(41870, origin = "1904-01-01")`. There's not a way to automatically detect from a number which version of Excel it was saved from, though perhaps it's in the file details somewhere.

Comment: RE: Did this come from Excel? 
> Yes. It comes from Excel file

Comment: You probably need to clean your data on excel (right mouse click > format cell > date). Once done you can save it as csv for instance, and start the R pipeline [not everything must be done in R! :) :) ]

Comment: If you use the `openxlsx` package. There is a detect_dates arguement in the read.xlsx function